# Fastest way to check equality with tolerance within a range?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, comparison

The following function compare two arrays, and returns true if all elements are equal taking in account a tolerance.

```
// Equal
template<typename Type>
bool eq(const unsigned int n, const Type* x, const Type* y, const Type tolerance)
{
    bool ok = true;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (std::abs(x[i]-y[i]) > std::abs(tolerance)) {
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Is there a way to beat the performances of this function ?

Comment: Is it causing speed issues in your program?

Comment: At the very least, pull the `std::abs(tolerance)` out of the loop. Not that the compiler can't already do that for you though...

Comment: This kind of task can benefit very heavily from strategic manual vectorization. But I highly doubt that a compiler will be capable of it here since the trip-count is unknown.

Comment: @chris : I work on supercomputers, and every instruction cost is important for this kind of low level functions.

Comment: @Vincent In that case you may very well need to sacrifice templates for some cold-metal speculative manual vectorization. It won't be easy though. :D

Comment: @Vincent: Consider writing in ASM then? Also not sure if the compiler would catch this, but you could return false from your `if` statement, instead of assigning ok to false, break, then return ok.

Comment: If the CPU has SIMD instructions, such as `_mm_abs_epi16` of Intel CPUs, you could compute differences eight items at a time. You would need to drop generics, though.

Comment: Optimizations might be possible with a better understanding of the specific use cases. For example, if the last objects of the two arrays are almost always very different but the first objects are almost always the same, then comparing in the other order might be an optimization. If the values are almost always exactly the same, then checking for equality before subtracting might be an optimization that avoids lots of subtractions and absolute value operations.

Comment: If the template Type is a primitive type (like double), then your supercomputer compiler should auto vectorize eq<double> for you. If your Type is a class, then make sure abs( <Type> ) and operator > ( <Type>, <Type> ) are inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute abs(tolerance) outside the loop.

You might try unrolling the loop into a 'major' loop and a 'minor' loop where the 'minor' loop's only jump is to its beginning and the 'major' loop has the 'if' and 'break' stuff.  Do something like `ok &= (x[i]-y[i] < abstol) & (y[i]-x[i] < abstol);` in the minor loop to avoid branching -- note `&` instead of `&&`.

Then partially unroll and vectorise the minor loop.  Then specialise for whatever floating-point types you're actually using and use your platform's SIMD instructions to do the minor loop.

Think before doing this, of course, since it can increase code size and thereby have ill effects on maintainability and sometimes the performance of other parts of your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid those return variable assignments, and precalculate the absolute value of tolerance:

```
// Equal
template<typename Type>
bool eq(const unsigned int n, const Type* x, const Type* y, const Type tolerance) {
    const Type absTolerance = std::abs(tolerance);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (std::abs(x[i]-y[i]) > absTolerance) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, if you know the tolerance will be always possitive there's no need to calculate its absolute value. If not, you may take it as a precondition.

Comment: Any decent compiler should come up with this itself, it would surprise me if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, you can roll a C++03 version with class functors also, it will be more verbose but should be equally efficient:

```
std::equal(x, x+n, y, [&tolerance](Type a, Type b) -> bool { return ((a-b) < tolerance) && ((a-b) > -tolerance); }
```

Major difference is dropping the abs: depending on `Type` and how `abs` is implemented you might get a conditional execution path extra, with lots of branch mispredictions, this should certainly avoid that. The duplicate calculation of a-b will likely be optimized away by the compiler (if it deems necessary).

Of course, it introduces an extra operator requirement for Type and if operators < or > are slow, it might be slower then abs (measure it).

Also, `std::equal` is a standard algorithm doing all that looping and early breaking for you, it's always a good idea to use a standard library for this. It's usually nicer to maintain (in C++11 at least) and could get optimized better because you clearly show intent.

Comment: I think you're missing a `-` in there, since it cannot be smaller and larger than `tolerance` at the same time.